# NoClassDefFoundError inside Jar with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have an application packaged with JAR, let's call this project `project A`, (it has an entry point class that is used in the maven assembly goal). I want to use this JAR inside another project, let's call this project `project B`; thus, I configured `pom.xml` to use dependency from the system. Here's the `pom.xml` file for `project B`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>JarsTest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>JarsTest</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.egehurturk</groupId>
      <artifactId>BanzaiServer</artifactId>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/BanzaiServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
           <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <archive>
                      <manifest>
                          <mainClass>org.example.App</mainClass>
                      </manifest>
                  </archive>
                  <descriptorRefs>
                      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                  </descriptorRefs>
              </configuration>

          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <source>8</source>
                  <target>8</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                      <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                      <goals>
                          <goal>single</goal>
                      </goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          </plugin>

      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And here's the `pom.xml` file for the project I use in `project A`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.egehurturk</groupId>
  <artifactId>BanzaiServer</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>BanzaiServer</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

<!--    TEST DEPENDENCIES   -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
          <version>5.7.0</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>2.23.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<!--    TEST DEPENDENCIES END   -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-cli/commons-cli -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.19.1</version>
              <dependencies>
                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                      <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                      <version>1.1.0</version>
                  </dependency>
              </dependencies>
          </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <archive>
                      <manifest>
                          <mainClass>com.egehurturk.httpd.EntryPoint</mainClass>
                      </manifest>
                  </archive>
                  <descriptorRefs>
                      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                  </descriptorRefs>
              </configuration>

          </plugin>

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <source>8</source>
                  <target>8</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                      <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                      <goals>
                          <goal>single</goal>
                      </goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          </plugin>

      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

In `project B`, I use classes that I provide in `project A`. For example, I import the class `com.egehurturk.httpd.HttpServer` from `project B`. However, when I tried to run the JAR of `project B` with `java -jar JarsTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` (after running `mvn package`), I got the following error:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/egehurturk/httpd/HttpServer
    at org.example.App.main(App.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.egehurturk.httpd.HttpServer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 1 more
```

I also looked inside `project A`'s JAR file, and the classes are present:

```sh
$ jar tf BanzaiServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar|
grep egehurturk
```

And the output is:

```
...
com/egehurturk/httpd/HttpServer.class
...
```

What's wrong with the packaging or the JARs?

Comment: Please consider: 1. Using `systemPath` is deprecated. 2. You don't use `jar-with-dependencies` for a `<dependency>` 3. Java 7 is pretty outdated. Furthermore, please show the command you ran that gave the strange output.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I included the command that gave the error. Thanks for your comment.